# Upgrade firmware without Slic3r and USB connection?

Tags: prusa-i3, firmware

When printing a part today on my Prusa i3 MK3, I was prompted to upgrade the firmware. I went to the website and [downloaded the firmware as a .hex file](https://www.prusa3d.com/drivers/).

When reading the attached firmware upgrade instructions, it seems there's only one way: use Slic3r and connect the printer via USB. These instructions are also [available online](https://manual.prusa3d.com/Guide/Upgrading+the+firmware+v1.4/66).

However, my printer is too far away from my PC and I'm printing from SD card only. Can I upgrade from SD card as well?

Hopefully next week I'll get the Raspberry Pi Zero W so I can use Octoprint for printing. Does that combination support upgrading the firmware?

I have tried:

- [this Prusa forum post](https://shop.prusa3d.com/forum/others-archive--f66/how-to-update-the-firmware-with-an-sd-card--t14767.html) suggests that upgrading via SD card is not possible.
- [this Prusa forum post](https://shop.prusa3d.com/forum/others-archive--f82/octoprint-firmware-upgrades-t3460-s10.html) mentions that there once was a way to upgrade the firmware via Octoprint, but the post is very old (last entry from January 2017)
- it's not a duplicate of [this 3D Printing question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6654/how-to-install-a-hex-firmware), since all solutions require a USB or serial connection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install a .hex firmware?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6654/how-to-install-a-hex-firmware)

Comment: What about a laptop? Can't you lend one? Updating from the Raspberry Pi should be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot update the firmware from an SD card.

Yes you can update from a Raspberry Pi (RPi). A RPi runs a Linux distribution, when you install the correct tools you should be able to update through USB using the RPi.

For simplicity and time it would be an idea to lend a laptop for a few minutes.

Comment: How does one flash firmware from a raspberry pi

Comment: @PerplexedDipole That is a different question - but a good one. Ask it in the stack!

Comment: @Trish: is this answer correct? Maybe. Is it helpful? Not much, since one needs to ask a new question. It would definitely be a better answer with an explanation on how to do it.

Comment: @ThomasWeller sometimes, one question pops up from the answer of one question.