# Export firmware as a .hex

Tags: firmware, repetier, arduino

Because `.hex` files can be installed without any need of an Arduino (serving as an ISP) to flash the firmware on Creality machines I was wondering, if firmware compiled via some other means (for example the [Repetier firmware](https://www.repetier.com/firmware/v100/) or [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software#toc2)) could be exported as a `.hex` file.

Comment: You might want to mention that this is for the Ender-3 specific controller board, as there is no bootloader, as per [TH3D Unified Firmware Package](https://www.th3dstudio.com/knowledge-base/th3d-unified-firmware/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Current versions of Arduino IDE

Use the menu option in the Arduino IDE:

**Sketch** ► **Export Compiled Binary**

See [post #6](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=131655.msg2445740#msg2445740) from the thread [How to get hex file from arduino files ?](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=131655.0):

> Well, since it was bumped it's worth mentioning there is a new way to
>   do this added in Arduino IDE 1.6.5:
>
> - Sketch > Export Compiled Binary
> - If you are doing this with an example then you will be prompted to save the sketch in another location.
> - Wait until the sketch has finished compiling.
> - Sketch > Show Sketch Folder
> - The .hex file will be in the sketch folder

Here is a screenshot for OS X:

> [image: Export compiled Binary menu option]

There is no need to fully compile, a simple verify will suffice. From [post #10](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=131655.msg3118445#msg3118445):

> Reopen Arduino, and open a sketch of your choice (use the Examples->Digital->Blink if you have no other sketches). Hit the Verify button to compile the sketch. Now, navigate to the build.path folder. You should see a bunch of files including one with a .hex extension.

---

### Older versions of Arduino IDE

If using an older version of the Arduino IDE, from [post #12](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=131655.msg3399334#msg3399334):

> Try this if using an older version of Arduino
>
> [Taking out HEX file from Arduino in 3 simple steps](http://arduinoisfun.blogspot.in/2016/01/taking-out-hex-file-from-arduino.html)

1. Open Arduino IDE
2. **File** ► **Preferences** menu

> [image: Arduino IDE Preferences menu]
>
> [image: Arduino IDE Preferences dialog]

3. Find "Show verbose output during " and check the "compilation" box
4. Locate the `preferences.txt` file and open it
5. Add the following line (this is the path to the directory where the hexfile will be stored):

   ```
   build.path=C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\hexfile
   ```
6. Change the following line

   ```
   export.delete_target_folder=true
   ```

   to

   ```
   export.delete_target_folder=false
   ```
7. Quit the Arduino IDE and restart it.
8. Now when you compile, the directory specified in `build.path` will contain the `.hex` file (along with other files which can be ignored)