# How to set Home Offsets and Manual Home definitions in Marlin correctly?

Tags: marlin, firmware, homing, endstop

I am using an Ender 3 and I have just upgraded to the Hero Me Gen 5 fan duct adapter. This has shifted the nozzle position. I also flashed some new Marlin 2 firmware and in the Hero Me manual it says to uncomment and change `#define MANUAL_Y_HOME_POS -9` to suit this change in nozzle position.

This has, however, not given me the right results. It did not center my prints but actually let the Y-axis grind upon going to `Y235`. Additionally, I noticed, that my printer must have been off-center from the beginning, because the X position of the nozzle has not changed due to the installation, but the printer homes to a point 5 mm inside the bed perimeters.

**So, if my printers endstops dictate an original home position of 3 mm *inside* the bed area for X and 15 mm outside the bed area for Y, how do I set this up correctly in Marlin 2?**

I think the relevant parts are

```
// The size of the print bed
#define X_BED_SIZE 235
#define Y_BED_SIZE 235

// Travel limits (mm) after homing, corresponding to endstop positions.
#define X_MIN_POS 5
#define Y_MIN_POS -15
#define Z_MIN_POS 0
#define X_MAX_POS 250
#define Y_MAX_POS 240
#define Z_MAX_POS 230
...
// Manually set the home position. Leave these undefined for automatic settings.
// For DELTA this is the top-center of the Cartesian print volume.
//#define MANUAL_X_HOME_POS 0
//#define MANUAL_Y_HOME_POS -9
//#define MANUAL_Z_HOME_POS 0
```

This is my idea, I would let the manual home pos be commented out as I do not know what it does. However, I also want the software endstops to correcly work as to not let the printer destroy it *aaaaand* my BLTouch to probe the bed and not the air or my bed clips using UBL when doing 3-point probing. Would this be correct? Where do I have to look to let the printer consider my bed clips(only 10 mm on both ends of the y-axis side of the bed)?

Comment: This question is very similar, and therefore a duplicate to [Recalibrating Home-position](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6399/recalibrating-home-position) and [How to center my prints on the build platform? (Re-calibrate homing offset)](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6375/how-to-center-my-prints-on-the-build-platform-re-calibrate-homing-offset). The answer to those questions describe in detail what you need to do. First question is specific for the Ender 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you wouldn't use the `MANUAL_xyz_HOME_POS` at all.

Home your machine.
Use a caliper or ruler to measure the distance between the nozzle and the edges of the print bed in both the X and Y direction.
If the nozzle was *off* the bed in both directions, input these measurements as *negative* `X_MIN_POS` and `Y_MIN_POS` values.
If it was *over* the bed in either of those directions, you'll need to input them as *positive* positions.

That should result in your nozzle to be exactly on the edge of the bed after a

```
G28 X Y
G1 X0 Y0
```

movement.

Comment: Oh my god, that is what I did and it didnt work, so then I wondered what I did wrong and came here to ask. But it did work! I just didn't flash the firmware, I must have forgotte nto turn the printer off and on again!

Comment: Still, how do I set the probe offsets or whatever correctly to not hit the clips? And is 5mm less of build volume normal?

Comment: You'll first want to set the probe offsets via `NOZZLE_TO_PROBE_OFFSET` relative to the nozzle.
The offsets for the actual probing would be set with `PROBING_MARGIN`, which defaults to 10 mm.