# Ender 3 Pro + SKR mini E3 1.2 + BLtouch doesn't work with downloaded bin file

Tags: creality-ender-3, bltouch, bigtreetech

I have a Ender 3 Pro V1. I installed the Bigtreetech SKR mini E3 V1.2 + TFT35 touchscreen + Antclabs BLTouch + a pre compiled bin from [here](https://marlin.crc.id.au/) .

- the board works
- the screen works
- the BLTouch is erratic

  - A) it tries to exceed the X limits and makes the loud clicking sound while performing the bed leveling. it even tries to move past the X end stop switch.
  - B) when printing, it moves to the far right rear corner and extrudes off of the bed.
  - C) OctoPrint can no longer connect with the printer.

I think this is just a problem with how the bed size is setup and it identifying the limits of the print. I just can't figure out how to configure and compile a working bin file.

Answer (score 1):

> A) it tries to exceed the X limits and makes the loud clicking sound while performing the bed leveling. it even tries to move past the X end stop switch.

This tells me that the firmware you use is faulty - it has a faulty bed-size or home.

> B)when printing, it moves to the far right rear corner and extrudes off of the bed.

This can be intended in the G-code, or bad homing, again, firmware home position.

> C) octoprint can no longer connect with the printer.

This, **again** is a thing that happens if the firmware is not configured properly or flashed correctly.

You might have accidentally chosen the wrong firmware distribution - your config points to the [Ender 3 - SKR Mini E3 v1.2 - BLTouch](https://marlin.crc.id.au/firmware/Ender%203%20-%20SKR%20Mini%20E3%20v1.2%20-%20BLTouch/), **not** the Ender 3 v1.5 or v2 (slightly different hardware), and possibly [adjust the proper homing position.](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6399/recalibrating-home-position)