# I want to change default start position to the center of Creality CR 10 Smart Pro

Tags: creality-cr-10, creality

Currently my 3D printer starts all projects from the lower left corner of the heatbed. I want to change the default setting to make the center of the heatbed the default position.

However, I have not found any documentation on how to do this. Can you help?

Comment: Why you want to do that, please explain, that makes no sense at all. Your project starts where you slice it. You can change it, but you need to change the firmware. And if you have done so you need to change the settings of the slicer also.

Comment: Isn't this set within whatever sliver you use, and the position of the piece on the bed?

Comment: Technically, [Recalibrating Home-position](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6399/recalibrating-home-position) may answer your question: you re-define 0 as the central bed position via trial and error, and need to swap the slicer to treat center of bed as 0 (which is a machine setting in cura)

Comment: My initial comment was meant to ask for an explanation why you want to set the origin in the middle of the bed, this is absolutely unnecessary, but you can do it. It is most certainly not a duplicate as it requires the firmware to be differently setup, e.g. use define `BED_CENTER_AT_0_0`. Only when this is set the firmware will work with half size bed length and width as you now need half bed sizes to go in positive and negative direction. Also the slicer needs to be adjusted for a center bed setup. This needs to be reopened, comments cleaned and the OP to add some additional info.

Comment: @Trish, please recheck your [double upvoted comment](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/20507/i-want-to-change-default-start-position-to-the-center-of-creality-cr-10-smart-pr#comment39054_20507), this is not how you put the origin in the center of the bed, please look into the Marlin sources. As it stands, you shift the origin to the middle, from where it uses the full bed width and length and can harm the printer as the effective print area is then a quarter of the bed surface. Referring to duplication is wrong and needs to be re-addressed.