# Model is cut off when printing despite showing correctly on slicer

Tags: creality-ender-3, troubleshooting

My printer is the Creality Ender 3 V2 Neo printer. Firmware is factory new.

You can see the problem below:
[image]
As you see, the long rectangle on the bottom is getting cut off when printed. Outline shown in red shows the path the printer is really taking. *(you can ignore the gray area, it is only there because both long rectangles are part of the same .stl file)*

Here is another view of the sliced print:
[image]

Additionally, you can see in this other picture:
[image]

- The print started quite a bit from the left edge
- The start G-code, which prints lines on the left, printed lines closer to the left edge than where the print started

Here is the start G-code:

```
; Ender 3 Custom Start G-code
G92 E0 ; Reset Extruder
G28 ; Home all axes
G29 ;
G1 Z2.0 F3000 ; Move Z Axis up little to prevent scratching of Heat Bed
G1 X0.1 Y20 Z0.3 F5000.0 ; Move to start position
G1 X0.1 Y200.0 Z0.3 F1500.0 E15 ; Draw the first line
G1 X0.4 Y200.0 Z0.3 F5000.0 ; Move to side a little
G1 X0.4 Y20 Z0.3 F1500.0 E30 ; Draw the second line
G92 E0 ; Reset Extruder
G1 Z2.0 F3000 ; Move Z Axis up little to prevent scratching of Heat Bed
G1 X5 Y20 Z0.3 F5000.0 ; Move over to prevent blob squish
```

Slicer settings:
[image]
[image]

How can I fix this? Is this due to the slicer? Due to the firmware? In either case, how do I change it?

Answer (score 2):

If I look at the printed middle rectangle, it appears that the printer is printing way too far to the right, or, your slicer used an incorrect bed size.

You should look into question [How to center my prints on the build platform? (Re-calibrate homing offset)](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6375/how-to-center-my-prints-on-the-build-platform-re-calibrate-homing-offset) or [Recalibrating Home-position](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6399/recalibrating-home-position?noredirect=1&lq=1) to center the print area and try to re-print the object again. Furthermore, as far as can be interpreted from the low res images, your printer may need some better leveling as some parts are too high and some too low.

Comment: Regarding the bed leveling, I raised the print head on purpose to peel the print off easier (since I was just testing). Then, after reading those links, my biggest question is: but why do the lines on the left (from the start g-code) print correctly? Does the printer use 2 coordinate systems, 1 for the start g-code, and 1 for the actual print?

Comment: @Milichip we don't know, maybe you could share some of the G-code (including the start of the rectangle) from the print, not just the start code. Or post a link to GitHub or a text sharing site. Also look at your settings in the slicer for the bed size and post these as well as the actual print area and bed size. If you have a prime line, this effectively reduces the print area, not much, just 0.4 mm.

Comment: Here is the g-code of the entire file (I didn't know you could just open it with a text editor): https://pastebin.com/geJRm4BG , I have also added a screenshot of the slicer settings in my original post

Answer (score 0):

### Your firmware and slicer operate on different sizes.

You need to update the firmware to update the bed size (and the 0-Offset) from the factory setting to the actual size. There is no way to alter the Maximum sizes via a direct connection.

Comment: I don't see how that can be true, considering the gcode that is being printed does make use of the left part of the build plate (altough only to clean the nozzle by printing 2 straight lines). It may be missing 5mm from the very edge, but that is not the problem in this post. Could you elaborate in a way that explains the current behavior?

Comment: if you demand the printer to go beyond the X or Y max position, the printhead will stop there, resulting in a clean cut.

Comment: That's not what I mean. If you look at the photos, you can see that the print started a little ways off from the left. However, the slicer shows the print would've started closer to the edge. In other words, yes, it makes sense for the right side to get cut off, but only because the left side started 2cm from the edge, for some reason. However, the "start g-code" lines started very close to the edge, which proves it is able to print there.